# POST returns 404 on Azure Text Analytics

Tags: rest, azure, nlp, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using the documentation found at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cognitive-services-text-analytics-quick-start/

I receive a 404 error in the response, when I POST the following data :

```
POST https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/topics HTTP/1.1
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: mykeyhere
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Host: westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
Content-Length: 1451699
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"documents":[{"id":"1","text":"Need to delete unwanted transaction data from QuickBooks? Look no further than the Transaction Pro Deleter. With a few clicks you have deleted unwanted QuickBooks transaction  ....."}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was not passing the operation id correctly to check status.